# How bydefault select an Item in - ng-repeat on options through use of model

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am using ng-repeat on option in select.

```
<select ng-model="mymodel">
        <option  ng-repeat="p in persons" value="{{p.id}}">{{p.name}}</option>
</select>
```

> $scope.persons= [
>                         {id:1,name:"tester11"},
>                         {id:2,name:'tester22'},
>                         {id:3,name:'tester33'},
>                         {id:4,name:'tester44'}
>                         ];

How can I make an option selectable means by default "tester33" should be selected 
through use of ng-model.

I know it is achievable through ng-options. But I want to try this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no perfect way to achieve this using `ng-repeat`, but here's a workaround:

```
<select ng-model="mymodel">
    <option ng-repeat="p in persons" ng-selected="p.name=='tester33'" value="{{p.id}}">{{p.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This just sets the option with `name='tester33'` but the model won't get updated until the user changes select value explicitly

NOTE: This is not a recommended way, you must use `ng-options` for complete functionality

Comment: Thanks a lot @Raghav for the valueable feedback.